# sqlcmd command to SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON

Tags: identity, sqlcmd

I am creating a batch file (.bat) with sqlcmd command containing sql insert query. But in which table it will insert data that has one IDENTITY column. Can anyone please help me with the sqlcmd command to SET IDENTITY_INSERT  ON?